# Serilog exception message not visible in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, .net-5, serilog

In my .Net 5 app I have a Serilog configuration which logs to Application Insights.

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "instrumentationKey": "xxx",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

For testing purposes, I created the test api method as follows

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
     logger.LogWarning("Warning message");
     logger.LogError(new CustomException("A custom exception message"), "Logger message");
     return Ok();
}
```

I would expect that the message passed in the `LogError` method should be shown in the AI. The result looks like this:
[image]

How can I make the message visible in logs? I tried to do custom telemetry converter by passing to MessageTemplate error message from log, but with no success.

Comment: To make the message visible in the Exceptions table in App Insights, you can refer to [C# Azure Functions and Application Insights - LogError not showing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67089436/15969115)

This is already an open issue[Log messages not showing up in App Insights](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/issues/142) and [Unable to log “Error” messages by Serilog's Application Insights sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/issues/138)

Answer (score 0):

Just configure in startup.cs:

```
var config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
config.ConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING").Value;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", $"{applicationName} - {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")}")
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithCorrelationId()
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles"))
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryClient(config), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .CreateLogger();
```